# mod_rewrite now broken?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, apache

I've upgraded mod_rewrite and my config stopped working ; I have this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

it's been working for years to match the default page. it's not working anymore and the log shows:

```
applying pattern '^index\.php$' to uri '/index.php'
```

obviously a new / has been prepend to the URI. Does anyone knows why the new version has changed that and if it's possible to fix it?

TIA

greg

Comment: My guess would be that your rewrite_base has changed. Without rewrite_base / the uri would normally start with the slash.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about this instruction!

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found out the problem ; it seems that mod_rewrite can't really be used inside the config files, only in .htaccess, or it will behave strangely (path problems).
A serie of problem lead my to think it was broken, as a matter of fact it has always been like that.